# How can I make sure that I am not penalized for using Google Rich Snippets?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, penalty

I am using the WordPress plugin [Yasr – Yet Another Stars Rating](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yet-another-stars-rating/) which is used to provide star ratings. It works fine but one of the users of this plugin posted following review:

> BEWARE of this plugin. It doesn't support the full Rich Snippet Schema types. In particular, it's missing the "Review" type. As a result, I as well as others, have been hit with a manual google penalty for spammy markup, because while our review articles should have been labelled as "Review" they're marked as "Product" with this plugin. Just google "yasr manual penalty" and you'll see. I asked this question to the creator of the plugin months ago but he chose to ignore it. Don't use it if you plan to include the rich snippet functionality and rely on google for your traffic.

I don't fully understand how these schemas work so I could not figure out if something indeed is wrong with the plugin. Here is the JSON-LD that the plugin generates:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
    "@context":"http:\/\/schema.org\/",
    "@type":"Product",
    "name":"(page title shows up here)",
    "Review": {
        "@type":"Review",
        "name":"(page title shows up here)",
        "author": {
            "@type": "Person", "name": "(website name)"
        }
        ,
        "datePublished":"2018-08-05T02:52:52+00:00",
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating", "ratingValue": "4.7"
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Is something wrong with the above snippet that can get me penalized? There is only one star rating posted by me. Users are not allowed to vote on the rating.

Comment: Have you tried Google's schema markup testing tools?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I ran my URL through `https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/` and it did not show any errors or warnings. :) However, I got worried because of the comment by one user about manual panelty.

Comment: Does the plugin allow you to change the JSON-LD? `"Review": {` must be `"review": {` (`r` instead of `R`). Google’s SDTT seems to ignore the case-error, but other consumers don’t do this necessarily. Anyway, this is an error without potential for a penalty.

Comment: Thanks for the input @unor. :) Is there anything else that I need to worry about? The comment from that one plugin has made me paranoid. To be clear, I am writing the reviews for actual products so `"@type":"Product"` should be okay, right?

Comment: If it's on a page that is not about a product, that would be misleading. Product pages typically mark up a lot more than just the name of the product. author should be a real name, not a websites name. The review title matching the product name is highly suspicious. Does it only list one review per page? If not, what does it look like with multiple reviews.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath There is only one review per page. :) Should I use some other plugin to create my rich snippets then?

Comment: @iKnowNothing does that mean the page is a critic review about a product. That's different again and the markup should start with the Review entity, which should contain details on the thing being reviewed. The problem with these plugins is that they have to make things up to include rich snippet viable markup, and with that, your markup is likely to be misleading in relation to what the page is actually about.

Comment: Yes @TonyMcCreath I explain all the features of the product like a smartphone or a laptop etc. in the article and list its pros and cons. Does that make the above Schema invalid or wrong? Is there any resource that I can read to clear up all my confusion?

Comment: Check how your structured data meets to the Google guidelines: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product and https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review